# How to redirect to another jsp

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I have a custom DL portlet in that we can attach multiple documents. I want to redirect to another jsp when user click on any document's name.

```
<td><a title="{{f.name}}" ng-click="viewFile(f.id);">{{f.name}}</a></td>
```

What i did is passed value `{{f.name}}` to

```
<A href="<portlet:renderURL><portlet:param name="jspPage" value="/other_jsp.jsp" /></portlet:renderURL>">{{f.name}}</A>
```

But its not working! URL coming like this:

```
http://www.xyz.net/group/human/documents/<portlet:renderURL><portlet:param name=
```

Comment: I put this 
<td><a title="{{f.name}}" ng-click="viewFile(f.id);" href="<portlet:renderURL><portlet:param name="jspPage" value="/matt.jsp"></portlet:renderURL>{{f.name}}</a></td>
the url comes is like broken :
localhost:port / /group/human/<portlet:renderURL><portlet:param name=

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tags are processed in server side, so it can't be used directly in HTML.

inside your JSP page, try as below,

> <portlet:renderURL var="myUrl"> <portlet:param name="jspPage"
>   value="/other_jsp.jsp" /> </portlet:renderURL>
>
> <A href="<%=myUrl %>">{{f.name}}

Also [this link](http://www.liferaysavvy.com/2013/11/working-with-liferay-urls.html) provides good information about liferay URLs.